# How to get url directory names in php array?

Tags: php

I have url like https://in.pinterest.com/sridharposnic/restinpeace/. 
I want url directories without domain in php array.
Example:-

```
$array[0] = 'sridharposnic';
$array[1] = 'restinpeace';
```

How we can extract these ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$url = 'https://in.pinterest.com/sridharposnic/restinpeace/';
$parsed = parse_url( $url );
$chunks = explode( '/', trim($parsed['path'],'/') );
print_r( $chunks );
```

Will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sridharposnic
    [1] => restinpeace
)
```